# Problem interpreting how to copy / paste tables within a presentation using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-slides

Apps script documentation appears to suggest it is possible to copy a table from one slide to another - but I can't seem to get it to work. This is the script I've used - any thoughbts on what I'm doing wrong?
Here's a [link](https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1927tG-7Sx3oRtFaQMfq-we4pn0pbnT_9Ag1qaQDJ3Yw/edit?usp=sharing) to an example of it in "use".

```
 * @OnlyCurrentDoc
 */
/*
Instructions copied from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/slides/slide#insertShape(ShapeType)
// Copy a table between presentations.
var otherPresentationSlide = SlidesApp.openById('presentationId').getSlides()[0];
var currentPresentationSlide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[0];
var table = otherPresentationSlide.getTables[0];
currentPresentationSlide.insertTable(table); // Also available for Layout, Master, and Page.*/

function test(){
var slide2 = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getSlides()[1];
var table = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation.getPageElementById('g2c6eee07fad_0_0').asTable();
slide2.insertTable(table);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var table = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation.getPageElementById('g2c6eee07fad_0_0').asTable();
```

#### To:

```
var table = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().getPageElementById('g2c6eee07fad_0_0').asTable();
```

`SlidesApp.getActivePresentation` is modified to `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()`.

But, in this case, I think that `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()` can be declared as a variable as follows.

```js
function test() {
  var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slide2 = slide.getSlides()[1];
  var table = slide.getPageElementById('g2c6eee07fad_0_0').asTable();
  slide2.insertTable(table);
}
```

Or, if you want to copy a table in the 1st page to 2nd page, the following modification might be able to be used.

```js
function test() {
  var slide = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  var slides = slide.getSlides();
  var srcTable = slides[0].getTables()[0];
  var dst = slides[1];
  dst.insertTable(srcTable);
}
```

- When I tested this modified script using your provided Google Slide, I confirmed that the script worked.

Comment: Thanks, such a daft mistake to miss off the brackets. I'm very inexperienced so a lot of what I do is because I've seen it done somewhere else and not ecause I understand why it needs to be done.

Comment: @Colin Wood Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In the case of the method `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation`, when `()` is added like `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation()`, it means that the method is executed with no argument. For example, when you see `console.log(SlidesApp.getActivePresentation)`, you can see `[Function]` in the log. And, when you see the methods of Class Presentation with `console.log(SlidesApp.getActivePresentation())`, you can see `getPageElementById: [Function]` in the log.

Comment: @Colin Wood As another approach, when the script editor is used, you put `SlidesApp.getActivePresentation().`, you can also see the methods by the autocomplete of the script editor.

Comment: I've hit another problem with this you might be interested in helping with?
I'm trying to update a table which appears on every slide of a particular type. I can now copy and paste the table to a master slide layout - but I'm struggling to find a way the table can be updated.
I've collecting the original table in an array and using splice to replace the old table with its updated version, but it's not proving effective. 
Here's a link to my efforts so far https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/1pu82aegWkzXUBjYTFQvvErVQRk3QbPWeJAtB7TLjzbk/edit#slide=id.p

Comment: I've managed to do it now. The solution is in the example I mentioned in the previous comment. It collects the table into an array then uses the remove method in a loop before running the insert method to add back the updated version.

Comment: @Colin Wood About your new question, I'm glad your new question was resolved.